# My dictionary is not functioning properly

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I was working on a tkinter project. It just a simple restaurant cashier (whatever you call it) project. It's not done yet but I was stuck on a problem.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Style

# The different type of items that the store is selling
drinks = {}
burgers = {}
french_fries = {}
ice_creams = {}

class Object:

    def __init__(self, name, price, type):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
        self.type = type
        exec('{}["{}"] = [{}, {}]'.format(self.type, name, price, self.type))

    def return_price(self):
        return self.price

    def get_price(self, amount):
        return self.price * amount

# Creating the object
Object('Coco Cola', 1.50, 'drinks')
Object('Sprite', 1.50, 'drinks')
Object('Apple Juice', 2.50, 'drinks')
Object('Orange juice', 2.50, 'drinks')
Object('Grape Juice', 2.50, 'drinks')
Object('Cheese and Ham', 3.75, 'burgers')
Object('Cheese', 4.00, 'burgers')
Object('Cheese and Fish', 3.50, 'burgers')
Object('All Meat', 5.50, 'burgers')
Object('Waffle Fries', 2.50, 'french_fries')
Object('Chili Cheese Fries', 2.75, 'french_fries')
Object('Polenta Fries', 3.50, 'french_fries')
Object('Potato Wedges', 3.50, 'french_fries')
Object('Strawberry', 3.50, 'ice_creams')
Object('Blueberry', 3.75, 'ice_creams')
Object('Black Berry', 3.00, 'ice_creams')
Object('Vanilla', 3.00, 'ice_creams')
Object('Chocolate', 3.50, 'ice_creams')



# This code is what gives me the result i specified at the bottom of my question
print(drinks)

# All the tkinter stuff
root = Tk()
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.style = Style()
root.style.theme_use('xpnative')


drink, burger, french_fry, ice_cream = StringVar(), StringVar(), StringVar(), StringVar()
drink_amount, burger_amount, french_fry_amount, ice_cream_amount = IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar()
subtotal, tax, total, change = IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar(), IntVar()
drink_amount.set(0)
burger_amount.set(0)
french_fry_amount.set(0)
ice_cream_amount.set(0)

Label(root, text='Restaraunt Cashier').grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=5)
Label(root, text='Drinks:').grid(row=1, sticky=W)
Label(root, text='Burgers:').grid(row=2, sticky=W)
Label(root, text='French Fries:').grid(row=3, sticky=W)
Label(root, text='Ice cream:').grid(row=4, sticky=W)
Label(root, text='Amount:').grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=E)
Label(root, text='Amount:').grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=E)
Label(root, text='Amount:').grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=E)
Label(root, text='Amount:').grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=E)
Label(root, text='Subtotal:').grid(row=1, column=4, sticky=W)
Label(root, text='Tax:').grid(row=2, column=4, sticky=W)
Label(root, text='Total:').grid(row=3, column=4, sticky=W)
Label(root, text='Change:').grid(row=4, column=4, sticky=W)

# Entry types
drink_entry = OptionMenu(root, drink, *drinks)
burger_entry = OptionMenu(root, burger, *drinks)
french_fries_entry = OptionMenu(root, french_fry, *drinks)
ice_cream_entry = OptionMenu(root, ice_cream, *drinks)

# Entry amount
drink_entry_amount = Entry(root, width=50)
burger_entry_amount = Entry(root, width=50)
french_fry_entry_amount = Entry(root, width=50)
ice_cream_entry_amount = Entry(root, width=50)

# Subtotal, tax, total, change, entries
subtotal_entry = Entry(root, width=50)
tax_entry = Entry(root, width=50)
total_entry = Entry(root, width=50)
change_entry = Entry(root, width=50)

# Gridding
drink_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, ipady=5)
burger_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, ipady=5)
french_fries_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, ipady=5)
ice_cream_entry.grid(row=4, column=1, ipady=5)
drink_entry_amount.grid(row=1, column=3, ipady=5)
burger_entry_amount.grid(row=2, column=3, ipady=5)
french_fry_entry_amount.grid(row=3, column=3, ipady=5)
ice_cream_entry_amount.grid(row=4, column=3, ipady=5)
subtotal_entry.grid(row=1, column=5, ipady=5)
tax_entry.grid(row=2, column=5, ipady=5)
total_entry.grid(row=3, column=5, ipady=5)
change_entry.grid(row=4, column=5, ipady=5)

entry_list = [
    'drink_entry', 'burger_entry', 'french_fries_entry', 'ice_cream_entry', 'drink_entry_amount', 'burger_entry_amount',
    'french_fries_entry_amount', 'ice_cream_entry_amount'
]

item_selected = []

def submit_clicked(event=None):
    global item_selected
    drink_amount.set(drink_entry_amount.get())
    burger_amount.set(burger_entry_amount.get())
    french_fry_amount.set(french_fry_entry_amount.get())
    ice_cream_amount.set(ice_cream_entry_amount.get())
    item_selected.append(drink.get())
    item_selected.append(burger.get())
    item_selected.append(french_fry.get())
    item_selected.append(ice_cream.get())
    item_selected = list(filter(None, item_selected))



submit_button = Button(root, text='Submit', command=submit_clicked)
submit_button.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=5)
root.grid_rowconfigure(5, minsize=20)


root.mainloop()
```

I'll walk you through the code:

1. Declared what the items the store sells as dictionaries
2. Create a class to make objects to create items of the each type selling in the store
3. Declaring variables that get the entry and option menu in the code below this.
4. Making the entries
5. Gridding it
6. Making a function that gets the entry and option menu and set it to the variables above.

I think the item_selected here is uneccessary.

So, the problem here is when I run, it give me something like this:

```
{'Coco Cola': [1.5, {...}], 'Sprite': [1.5, {...}], 'Apple Juice': [2.5, {...}], 'Orange juice': [2.5, {...}], 'Grape Juice': [2.5, {...}]}
```

What I expected from the code:

```
{'Coca Cola': [1.5, 'drinks'], 'Sprite': [1.5, 'drinks'], 'Apple Juice': [2.5, 'drinks'], 'Orange juice': [2.5, 'drinks'], 'Grape Juice': [2.5, 'drinks']}
```

I'm believe my problem does not interfere with the tkinter code, I might be wrong but I just want people pinpoint my mistakes cause I can't right now.

Comment: You're adding the dictionary to itself. You haven't told us what you want to do instead, so we can't help you fix it. Please post a [mcve] - less code, and more description of what the code should do. Remove all the tkinter stuff if it's not relevant to the question. Also, if I understand the problem correctly, the whole thing probably would've been avoided if you didn't use `exec`. Don't use `exec`.

Comment: Why not use exec? What's the problem with that

Comment: You probably wouldn't have made this mistake if you hadn't used `exec`. Or, phrased differently, `exec` makes the code needlessly hard to read.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

As I think @Aran-Fey diagnosed in the comments, your issue has to do with your `exec` call in `Object.__init__`, which isn't doing what you expect. When do:

```
exec('{}["{}"] = [{}, {}]'.format(self.type, name, price, self.type))
```

with `self.type` equal to the name of one of your dictionaries (like `"drinks"`), you are running this Python statement:

```
drinks[...] = [..., drinks]
```

That is, you're assigning a reference to the dictionary as a part of a value in the dictionary. I suspect you want to that value to include the string `"drinks"` instead of a reference to the dictionary named `drinks`. For that you'd need `{!r}` in the format string.

But better yet, do away with the `exec` call entirely! Variable names should not be data. If you have a data item like the string `"drinks"` and you want that to let you look up a dictionary, use it as a key in another level of dictionary.

So rather than four top-level variables:

```
drinks = {}
burgers = {}
french_fries = {}
ice_creams = {}
```

Make just one (which I've uncreatively named `data`, you might come up with a better name):

```
data = {"drinks": {}, "burgers": {}, "french_fries": {}, "ice_creams": {}}
```

Then instead of needing `exec`, you can just index the dictionary as necessary:

```
data[self.type][name] = [price, self.type]
```

There are some other issues in your code as well. It's very weird that you're creating `Object` instances exclusively for their side-effects (you throw away each instance immediately after it's created). That could make sense if the constructor inserts the object into a data structure (as for instance, `TKinter` types often do). If you only care about side effects, just move the code from `Object.__init__` into a top level function and do away with the class!

Several of your `Entry` objects appear to be referencing the wrong dictionary: `burger_entry = OptionMenu(root, burger, *drinks)` should probably have `*burgers` as its last argument (or `*data['burgers']` if you change the data structures as I suggested above).

Comment: I see. Thank you for helping me. I couldn't thank you enough. But i just have one more question. Is it that dangerous to use exec or eval?

Comment: It's not dangerous to use it the way you did here (with data you fully control), though, as I said in the answer, it's still not a good idea. People will often say that it's dangerous to use `eval` or `exec` because if untrusted data gets into the string you're running, the call can do just about anything. For a taste, try this call with a bogus `price` argument: `Object('Coco Cola', '1.50, "drinks"];from tkinter import messagebox as m;m.showinfo("bad stuff");[0', "drinks")`. The `exec` is now popping up a window, and it could do more (e.g. changing your password or deleting your hard drive).

Comment: So, you're saying try to avoid using them?

Comment: Generally, yes, you should avoid `eval` and `exec`. They're always hard to debug, and can be very bad for security in some situations.

Comment: Thank you very much